# JQUERY: Hide Dropdownlist1 when Dropdownlist2 = "certain value"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Basically I'm trying to hide dropdownlist1 when dropdownlist2's selected value is "example".

Is this possible with jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its possible, just bind a function to the change event and look at the value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mAmQ/8/)**

```
$('#dp1').change(function(){
    if(this.value === 'example'){
        $('#dp2').hide();  
    }else{ // If you want it to show on other values
        $('#dp2').show(); 
    }
});
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/change/)**

Comment: Your exmample doesn't work properyly, you are are setting the drop down equal to example instead of checking the value. Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/4mAmQ/5/

Comment: heh yeah I caught that a second before and changed it :P, thanks though.

Comment: @Thai I considered that but the OP didn't ask it to do that, Ill add it though.

Comment: Thanks @pixelbobby I like the lowercase check, but I prefer to use the pure JS way of getting the value rather that using .val(), micro optimization I know :)

Comment: Np.  You're right and I agree with you; I was troubleshooting the code and forgot to put it back to `this.val`.  _good call._